# The PHP decrypt function for this resolution (look at)

Tags: php, ios, encryption, aes, rijndael

After a long time searching for the best way to en/decrypt data between PHP and iOS, I'm now asking you for a function in PHP.

I'm using this framework (https://gist.github.com/2507415) in Objective-C and my code is:

```
NSString *string= @"Affe";
NSString *key = @"12345678901234567890123456789012";
NSLog(%@,[string AES256EnryptWithKey:key];
```

Output: **UUfn34iyNlSK40VaehloaQ==**

I've tried so much in PHP but nothing works. I hope somebody knows how to decrypt this server-side.

Comment: So in summary, "*Give me teh codez*"- If you've tried so much, show us what you've tried.

Comment: Have you tried the [mcrypt](http://ch2.php.net/mcrypt) library?

Comment: Hi i really tried all, and on end of all I was so confused about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems to be using AES 128, with no IV in ECB mode and PKCS-7 compatible padding, try [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#105173):

```
function encrypt($str, $key)
{
    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('rijndael-128', 'ecb');
    $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
    $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt('rijndael-128', $key, $str, 'ecb'));
}

function decrypt($str, $key)
{   
    $str = mcrypt_decrypt('rijndael-128', $key, base64_decode($str), 'ecb');

    $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('rijndael-128', 'ecb');
    $pad = ord($str[($len = strlen($str)) - 1]);
    return substr($str, 0, strlen($str) - $pad);
}
```

**PS: I had forgotten about the base64 encoding, it's fixed now.**

Answer (score 2):

I dont know much about IOS, but I've implemented same logic recently between a PHP and Java API.
I needed to encrypt the communication between an android device and a PHP backend.

I wrote a small summary, maybe the PHP part may help you out.

http://blog.cwill-dev.com/2012/10/09/encryption-between-javaandroid-and-php/

You should have a look at the [mcrypt library](http://ch2.php.net/mcrypt), as Louis already mentioned.

Comment: it looks very nice..i will try now

Comment: Don't use this, it implements PKCS #5 padding.

Comment: do i need this or not (pkcs5) - i've read so much about that its important...

Comment: @swarley: It's nice to have (specially for binary data), but PKCS #7 is better and that's the one your gist implements. Furthermore, that link uses an IV, CBC mode and AES-128 - your gist uses different things (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

Seem like PHP not support AES 256, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-algos.php.

I have found implementations using Rijndael-256 but I'm not sure if it works properly:

http://kix.in/2008/07/22/aes-256-using-php-mcrypt/

http://snipperize.todayclose.com/snippet/php/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-AES-256--17234/

Comment: It [does support AES (hint: MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php). Why you are quoting the **hash functions** supported is beyond me.

Comment: By the way, the third link (snipperize) is down.